# Show that $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$.

When $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ then $X-\{a\}$, where $a \in X$ is homeomorphic to $Y-\{f(a)\}$. Assuming $S^1$ and $[0,1)$ are homeomorphic, I remove a point $a$ other than $0$. We see that $[0,1)-\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1-\{f(a)\}$. But  $S^1-\{f(a)\}$ is connected while $[0,1)-\{a\}$ is not. This is a contradiction which proves the claim.

However when I remove $0$, We see that  $ [0,1)-\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1-\{f(0)\}$ which is in fact true. This shows $S^1$ is indeed homeomorphic to $[0,1)$ opposite of what I am trying to show. So I am not sure what has gone wrong in these reasonings.

Comment: $S^1$ is compact but $[0,1)$ is not

Comment: But I have not learned compactness yet. Also I don't understand why I am getting conflicting conclusion just by choosing a different point Since $a \in X$ does not require to be any specific point.

Comment: $X \setminus \{x\}$ can be homomorphic to $Y \setminus \{y\}$ without $X$ being homeomorphic to $Y$.  Removing any point from $S^1$ leaves it connected, but this is not true of $[0, )$ and that does show they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: This is a good point that illustrates the subtlety of how this works: you remove a point *from the domain*, not the range (this comes for free of course). So what you'll want to do is take your proposed homeomorphism and consider the preimage of a point *that is not zero* and remove that point. There is a little bit of back and forth juggling to do in your head, but that's to be expected given the bijective nature of a homeomorphism. It's not that any given point will work but that *some* point achieves what you're trying to do. The preimage of $0$ is obviously not going to work as you showed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$. Indeed, if you remove ***any*** point from $S^1$, you get a connected space while if you remove *any point that is not equal to* $0$ from $[0,1)$, you get a disconnected space. Thus, $S^1$ and $[0,1)$ cannot be homeomorphic.

In details, assume that there exists a homeomorphism $f \colon S^1 \rightarrow [0,1)$, show that $f|_{S^1 \setminus \{ f^{-1}(1/2) \}}$ must be a homeomorphism between ${S^1 \setminus \{ f^{-1}(1/2)}\}$ and $[0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1)$ and show that this is not possible.

Your mistake is that if they are homeomorphic, then connectedness should be preserved *regardless the point you remove*, which must be arbitrary.

Comment: I see. So, If $S^1$ and $[0,1)$ were homeomorphic, removing any point would preserve their homeomorphism but this is not true in this case which proves they are not homeomorphic right? Can you please explain the last sentence?

Comment: Exactly. In the case you mention, removing $0$, you are removing a specific point. To be homeomorphic is a property that must hold if you remove any point. If there is only one point for which it does not hold, then they are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand your confusion, actually it is more like a matter of logic:

You were assuming the statement $P$ (that they are homeomorphic) at the very beginning, your aim is to deduce that $\neg P$ (that they are not homeomorphic) but you obtain by another way that the  second argument that they are homeomorphic (that $[0,1)\setminus\{0\}$...), this does NOT show that it is in fact $P$ because you have had assumed at the beginning, this is not a way of showing a statement by assuming at the very beginning.

Comment: I don't follow it. Can you elaborate a bit please?